# long running task in web service

Tags: asp.net, multithreading, wcf, iis

I have a .NET web service [WCF hosted in IIS] which now needs to implement a method which would be a long running task.
What is the best practice for this implementation in order to avoid blocking threads from ASP.NET Thread pool?
Moreover Does it make sense to use Task parallel library [TPL] in WCF?
Thanks a lot in advance for your support

Comment: I'd recommend using the async/await pattern.  It won't block and will use resources more efficiently if implemented correctly.

Comment: Do you mean that the async/await pattern would be fine also if the WCF is IIS hosted?Wouldn't it grab threads from ASP.NET thread pool? And what about the use of TPL in WCF?

Comment: I forgot to mention that the long runing task is CPU bound, not I/O bound.

Comment: Async/await is appropriate for I/O and CPU bound stuff.  And yes, IIS is okay as the host.  It's not really grabbing threads from the pool.  It will release a thread while it awaits and get a new one when the await is completed.

Answer (score 2):

Threads in the pool are not really a scarce resource. Unless you plan to consume hundreds at the same time this is not something to worry about.

A long-running background task would be best implemented as a `LongRunning` `Task`. Be sure to catch any errors so that you know about bugs.

Also note, that background work can disappear at any time when the worker process shuts down (deployment, crash, reboot, ...).

The easiest way to do this would be to not do background work at all. Maybe a client can run a really long running WCF request and you do all of that on the request thread. That handles threading and errors for you.